# configuring/running oozie 3.3.2 and hadoop 1.2.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I have been working with different versions of both hadoop and oozie to get them working together but haven't suceeded. Recently i considered the two versions(hadoop 1.2.0 and oozie 3.3.2) which are put together under hortonworks 1.3 data platform so i figured they will work together. I configured and run the hadoop on a single node in pseudo distributed mode.

Although i was able to build the oozie successfully including the jar files from hadoop, while i try to run it i'm faced with the following error on `http://hostname:11000/oozie`. Any help is greatly appreciated, it's so frustrating to haven't figured it out for weeks.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Filter execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:84)

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/util/List;
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.PseudoAuthenticationHandler.getUserName(PseudoAuthenticationHandler.java:124)
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.PseudoAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(PseudoAuthenticationHandler.java:160)
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:349)
org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:131)
org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:84)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 logs. Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
```